# Londo refers to his wives as famine, pestilence, and death, which are which?

Tags: babylon-5

In "War Prayer" s1e07 Londo refers to his wives as "famine, pestilence, and death". Later we meet Daggair, Mariel, and Timov in "Soul Mates" s2e07.

From what we know from these episodes is there a mapping of these three women to the three concepts?  Is it potentially foreshadowing that one would bring Londo death (as one almost did)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [this interview](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/guide/029.html) with Peter David (who wrote the episode "Soul Mates", originally entitled "*Pestilence, Famine and Death*"):

> **"Daggair was Pestilence. Timov was Famine. Mariel was Death."**
>
> "At first I was going to have all their names be reflections of the
>   titles "assigned" them by Londo, but I decided that would be too
>   cutesy. The only holdover from that idea is Timov, whose name
>   backwards is, of course, Vomit. (I'll never forget Jane Carr coming
>   over to me the fifth day of shooting and saying in that accented voice
>   of hers, "Peter...did you *know* that my character's name is vomit
>   spelled backwards?" Uhhhh...well, yeah...)"
>
> "You all realize, of course, that Londo is--by process of elimination--
>   War."

[image]

Comment: Timov, completely missed that.  Also, is Londo War or is Adira?  Considering how he changed on her death...

Comment: @TysonoftheNorthwest - Londo is War. He's the harbinger of the Shadow War.

Comment: Wow, so the Londo = War thing is actually canon? I thought it was just an (albeit very convincing) interpretation.

Answer (score 3):

In the Babylon 5 wikia notes section on Timov (Vomit spelled backwards):

> According to Peter David, who wrote ("Soul Mates"), Timov corresponds to "famine." in the 4 Horsemen of the Apocalypse theme presented with Mollari and his wives. With Timov (Famine), Daggair (Pestilence), and Mariel (Death), Londo himself completes the set as "War".